# Why I get View code implementing before the Controller code?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, asynchronous

I write my code in MVC. Now my code looks like:

```
// NewsfeedViewController.swift
var recentNewsController: RecentNewsController?

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(self.credentials.recentNewsURL)\(self.pageNum)&pageSize=\(self.pageSize)").validate().responseJSON { response in
        print("NewsfeedViewController")
        do {
            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

            for _ in 0...json.count {
                self.recentNewsController!.recentNews.append(RecentNewsModel(json: json))
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

And in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    recentNewsController = RecentNewsController(nibName: "RecentNewsController", bundle: nil)
    self.controllersArray.append(recentNewsController)

    self.pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: self.controllersArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 60.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 110))
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageMenu!.view)
}
```

where `RecentNewsController`:

```
var recentNews = [RecentNewsModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let newsCell = UINib(nibName: "newsCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(newsCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    print("showed2")
    print(recentNews)
}
```

When I run my app, in logs I get the next:

```
showed2
[]
NewsfeedViewController
```

So, why I get at first `showed2` and `[]`(empty `recentNews` array) from the `RecentViewController` and just later I get `"NewsfeedViewController"` from my NewsfeedViewController?

My main purpose is filling my `recentNews` array and use it in `RecentNewsController`. But now I get an empty array there

Comment: because viewDidLoad() called before viewDidAppear() - learn viewController life cycle

Answer (score 1):

Seems correct to me, the order of events are always `viewDidLoad` `viewWillAppear` `viewDidAppear` for viewcontrollers. your `print("NewsfeedViewController")` would only print after the webservice call back came back from the server, so would assume it to be last always

Comment: So, I need to paste all inside of `viewDidLoad`, yes? Now I'll try it

Comment: probably all should be in the callback from the webservice call, cause your `recentNews` array wont be updated till then, but i dont really know what you are trying to achieve anyway

Comment: it's a blog app. So, I need to get from the server response and show it in my view

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

That is expected to happen as there are 2 things that cause this:

1. `viewWillAppear:` is called after `viewDidLoad:`
2. Network Request is on a background thread, so basically even if you call it first it will allow other instructions to continue. ([Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) is a good introduction)

### Solution

If you want to load data before adding your controller, then you can do the request and when the request is finished, you can call adding your controller inside the view. (Note the GCD block, **all UI Operations must be made on Main Thread**)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(self.credentials.recentNewsURL)\(self.pageNum)&pageSize=\(self.pageSize)").validate().responseJSON { response in
        print("NewsfeedViewController")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            do {
                let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                
                for _ in 0...json.count {
                    self.recentNewsController!.recentNews.append(RecentNewsModel(json: json))
                }
            }
            
            self.pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: self.controllersArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 60.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 110))
            self.view.addSubview(self.pageMenu!.view)
        })
        
    }
}
```